# Obtain child anchor element within WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, dom, webbrowser-control

**Preamble**

I'm using the `WebBrowser` control, which a user will interact with, so a solution will need to work with a visible `WebBrowser` control.

**Question**

How do I check if an element has an anchor as a child? All browsers are able to distinguish that an element contains an anchor (`<a href=""...`), and offers "open in new tab" functionality. That is what I am attempting to replicate. However, when I right click on a `HtmlElement` I'm only able to obtain the parent element.

**Example**

Taking the BBC website as an example, when I right click on the highlighted element (picture below), my output is `DIV`, but viewing the source code there is an anchor element as a child of this `div`.

[image: bbc homepage example]

**SSCCE**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BrowserLinkClick
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private WebBrowser wb;
        private bool firstLoad = true;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            wb = new WebBrowser();
            wb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            Controls.Add(wb);
            wb.Navigate("http://bbc.co.uk");
            wb.DocumentCompleted += wb_DocumentCompleted;
        }

        private void Document_MouseDown(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.MouseButtonsPressed == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                HtmlElement element = wb.Document.GetElementFromPoint(PointToClient(MousePosition));
                //I assume I need to check if this element has child elements that contain a TagName "A"
                if (element.TagName == "A")
                    Debug.WriteLine("Get link location, open in new tab.");
                else
                    Debug.WriteLine(element.TagName);
            }
        }


        private void wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (firstLoad)
            {
                wb.Document.MouseDown += new HtmlElementEventHandler(Document_MouseDown);
                firstLoad = false;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Please test any proposed solution using the BBC website and the highlighted headline** (the headline changes, but the DOM remains the same).

Answer (score 2):

You have to get the child elements of `element` before checking if it's an anchor:

```
HtmlElement element = wb.Document.GetElementFromPoint(PointToClient(MousePosition));
foreach (HtmlElement child in element.Children)
{
    if (child.TagName == "A")
        Debug.WriteLine("Get link location, open in new tab.");
}
```

Comment: Sadly this still isn't returning the `a` tag for my example. Can you try with the BBC example from my original post and see if that's the case for you? The news item has changed, but the DOM structure remains the same.

Answer (score 2):

To access the needed properties you need to cast the `HtmlElement` to one of the unmanaged MSHTML interfaces, e.g. [`IHTMLAnchorElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741833%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You have to add `Microsoft HTML Object Library` COM reference to your project.
(The file name is `mshtml.tlb`.)

```
foreach (HtmlElement child in element.Children)
{
    if (String.Equals(child.TagName, "a", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        var anchorElement = (mshtml.IHTMLAnchorElement)child.DomElement;
        Console.WriteLine("href: [{0}]", anchorElement.href);
    }
}
```

There are plenty of such interfaces but MSDN will help you choose. :)

[Scripting Object Interfaces (MSHTML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801967%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Sadly this still isn't returning the `a` tag for my example. Can you try with the BBC example from my original post and see if that's the case for you? The news item has changed, but the DOM structure remains the same.

Comment: You may use a recursive method the check if any of the `HtmlElement.Children` is a `mshtml.IHtmlAnchorElement`; if none then set the current element to its parent element and call the same method recursively (of course you should skip the already checked elements).

Answer (score 2):

I propose you the following solution: 
url variable will have url of your desired output, you'll be able to see it in debugger window.

```
private void Document_MouseDown(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.MouseButtonsPressed == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            HtmlElement element = wb.Document.GetElementFromPoint(PointToClient(MousePosition));
            //I assume I need to check if this element has child elements that contain a TagName "A"
            if (element.TagName == "A")
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Get link location, open in new tab.");
                var urlRaw = element.OuterHtml;
                string hrefBegin = "href=";
                var idxHref = urlRaw.IndexOf(hrefBegin) + hrefBegin.Length + 1;
                var idxEnd = urlRaw.IndexOf("\"", idxHref + 1);
                var url = urlRaw.Substring(idxHref, idxEnd - idxHref);
                Debug.WriteLine(url);
            }

            else
                Debug.WriteLine(element.TagName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @TEK does it help?

Comment: The parsing of the URL from the anchor isn't the problem, but rather getting the anchor tag when it's a child of other elements (yes, parsing the link out is a future problem, but I can't even get the anchor yet). Use the BBC homepage from my original post, you'll see I'm not able to find an anchor when right clicking on one of the headlines. Yet, the `WebBrowser` control with a default context menu is able to distinguish there is an anchor, as are other web browsers.

Comment: What do you consider as anchor? Parent tag or sibling tag? Can you provide some example of what output you expect?

Comment: From my original post: "All browsers are able to distinguish that an element contains an anchor (`<a href=""...`), and offers "open in new tab" functionality. That is what I am attempting to replicate." 

In the future, I will override the context menu of the `WebBrowser` control, and want to provide the "open in new tab" functionality. In order to do so, I need to see if where the user right clicks contains a link, so I can provide them with the option to open in a new tab.

Comment: so, if user clicks at url, you expect to track not "a" but "a href" ?

Comment: Yes, ultimately I need the address, so need to track the a href. But a previous comment noted, there appears to be some issue with the BBC UK site that is preventing me from obtaining a child anchor element from its parent.

Answer (score 2):

There has to be something else wrong with your program. On the BBC website your code works for the news articles (although I see the non UK version of the site). On other websites where there are anchor elements as children the code below works

```
 private void Document_MouseDown(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.MouseButtonsPressed == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            HtmlElement element = wb.Document.GetElementFromPoint(PointToClient(MousePosition));
            if (element.Children.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (HtmlElement child in element.Children)
                {
                    if (child.TagName == "A")
                        Debug.WriteLine("Get link location, open in new tab.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //I assume I need to check if this element has child elements that contain a TagName "A"
                if (element.TagName == "A")
                    Debug.WriteLine("Get link location, open in new tab.");
                else
                    Debug.WriteLine(element.TagName);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The code I posted in my original post is my testing program for these solutions provided so far. To clarify,  you're able to right click the news item that is highlighted by a red box in my example image (news item has changed, the DOM hasn't), and you're able to get the debug output "Get link location, open in new tab."?, because depending on where I click on that news item (element), all I get is either `DIV` or `SPAN`.

Are you able to post a screenshot of what you're right-clicking and the output?

Comment: Yes, your code alone works for BBC. Maybe the UK version is different however. I always get the anchor tag no matter where I click on it. Here is a pic: http://imgur.com/4uAB04p. I tried on other sites where the anchor is behind a header tag and the above code works.

Comment: Thank you for posting the image... I was starting to think I was going crazy! This really is most puzzling, then. It's simply not showing an element with a tagname "A" for those news items. :/

Comment: Maybe there is an issue with the mouse position on your side. If you click other places do you get what you would expect?

Comment: Yeah, if I right click the navigation bar, or pretty much any other obvious link, I get the "Get link location, open in new tab.". It's just these news items with nested child elements that appear to be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The challenge with bbc web site, that it have little bit non standard approach toward their url.
Below goes one of the samples of their a href:

```
<A tabIndex=-1 aria-hidden=true class=block-link__overlay-link href="http://www.bbc.com/news/world-africa-36132482" rev=hero5|overlay>Barbie challenges the 'white saviour complex' </A>
```

so, you need to use two parts in if:
1. element.TagName == "A"
2. check attribute href like this: element.GetAttribute("href")

Those two checks can give you guaranty that you deal with something with tag a, and that tag a has attribute href. See another example of usage:

```
private void Document_MouseDown(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.MouseButtonsPressed == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            HtmlElement element = wb.Document.GetElementFromPoint(PointToClient(MousePosition));
            //I assume I need to check if this element has child elements that contain a TagName "A"
            if (element.TagName == "A" && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(element.GetAttribute("href")))//it means we have deal with href
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Get link location, open in new tab.");
                var url = element.GetAttribute("href");
                Debug.WriteLine(url);
            }

            else
                Debug.WriteLine(element.TagName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I really appreciate your continued efforts, but depending where I right-click on that particular news headline element it either outputs `DIV` or `SPAN`, I just can't get the child anchor (`A`) element at all. In fact, what I've now observed, is that if the anchor is child of *any* element from *any* website, I cannot access it. My `WebBrowser` control hasn't been tinkered with, and I use the simple sample I posted as a base for any of these solutions posted, so I am not entirely sure what is going on.