# Detect parents' and grandparents' links in Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, cefsharp

I am making a Web Browser in C# and displaying custom context menus based on the element right clicked by the user. I am having trouble figuring out which elements should be treated as links?

```
if (el_tag == "a")
    showLinkMenu();

else if (el_tag == "img" && parent_tag == "a")
    showAdvancedMenu();

else if (el_tag == "img")
    showImgMenu();
```

Shot1: [Google chrome detected this as a link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PQ6G.png)

Shot2: [Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtO4E.png) a > div > div > div > div > img

What should I do to detect such links?

Comment: Consider that existing web browsers don't do it that way.  Instead, each nested element receives the click event and handles it according to its own logic, so in the case of your example the a, and the four divs, and the image would all receive that click event, from outer to inner (in order).  If the anchor has a href, it's logic says that should become a navigation action and therefore interrupts further propagation.

Comment: `var p = el_tag; while (1) { p = p.parentElement.tagName; if (p == 'a' || p == 'body') { alert(p); break; } }`
How about this?

Comment: ? I thought you said you were working in C#

Comment: Using CefSharp and sending commands to execture JS

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate up the list of parent tags and call it a link if any of them are an `<a>` with an `href` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend implementing your own `IContextMenuHandler` and use the built in `CefMenuCommand`'s and `TypeFlag`'s to help you. With this, you can add or remove context menu items based on the element that has been right-clicked.

`MenuHandler.cs`

```
internal class MenuHandler : IContextMenuHandler
{
    private const int SaveImage = 26503;
    private const int OpenLinkNewTab = 26501;

    public event EventHandler OnSaveImage = delegate { };

    void IContextMenuHandler.OnBeforeContextMenu(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IContextMenuParams parameters, IMenuModel model)
    {
        if(parameters.TypeFlags.HasFlag(ContextMenuType.Media) && parameters.HasImageContents)
        {
            model.AddItem((CefMenuCommand)SaveImage, "Save image");
        }
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameters.UnfilteredLinkUrl))
        {
            model.AddItem((CefMenuCommand)OpenLinkNewTab, "Open link in new tab");
        }
    }

     bool  IContextMenuHandler.OnContextMenuCommand(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IContextMenuParams parameters, CefMenuCommand commandId, CefEventFlags eventFlags)
     {
        return false;
     }

    void IContextMenuHandler.OnContextMenuDismissed(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame)
    {
        if ((int)commandId == SaveImage)
        {
            OnSaveImage?.Invoke(this, new ImageSaveEventArgs(parameters.SourceUrl)); //ImageSaveEventArgs is just a class with one property that houses the source url of the image to download.
        }
    }

    bool IContextMenuHandler.RunContextMenu(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IContextMenuParams parameters, IMenuModel model, IRunContextMenuCallback callback)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then wherever you create your `ChromiumWebBrowser` instance, you can do something like this:

```
ChromiumWebBrowser browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser();
MenuHandler menuHandler = new MenuHandler();
menuHandler.OnSaveImage +=  Handler_OnSaveImage;
browser.MenuHandler = menuHandler;

private void Handler_OnSaveImage(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DownloadImage(((ImageSaveEventArgs)e).SourceUrl);
}
```

Note, this is just an example of using the built-in `IContextMenuHandler` to obtain what the user has right-clicked, and then handling my own event so I can implemented the required behaviour. In this case, the ability to download a file from the URL.

See [MenuHandler.cs](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp.WinForms.Example/Handlers/MenuHandler.cs) on `CefSharp`'s GitHub page for more details and other examples.

Comment: my code is much simpler and meets all my requirements. thanks anyways! My C# code was already written was confused about the JavaScript.

Comment: @WorldBoss Fair enough. I tried to roll my own in the past when using the `WebBrowser` control (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36767938/obtain-child-anchor-element-within-webbrowser-control) and had a thoroughly  miserable time. When it comes to HTML documents, there are a million and one edge cases, so I prefer to use an engine that has probably solved it better than I ever will. If you have small requirements and you've met them, then rolling your own is cool! :-)

Comment: Thanks for sharing that link!